# VIM, Run a command on multiple files

Tags: vim, batch-file, substitution

I have a bunch of sass files and my designer used the wrong syntax. I wanted `:margin-top 1px` but he did `margin-top: 1px`

So I easily wrote a sub command:

```
:rubydo sub! /([\w-]+):/,':\1'
```

So that works and fixes all the colons and moves them in the place I want. I have about 50 sass files in a `stylesheets` directory. How can I run this command on all my files in one shot? I'm not really sure how to go about this in `vim`. Maybe something to do with `grep`? I couldn't tell ya.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See this: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:argdo

I learned this command right now, but the help is clear.

Go for:

```
:args *.css
:argdo %s/\([[:alpha:]-]\+\):/:\1/ge | update
```

Comment: +1 for `argdo`, `bufdo` is too general. You can also create an argument list local to the window with `:argl` if you don't want to change your global arg list.

Comment: I found this article on this subject to be very helpful: http://www.ibrahim-ahmed.com/2008/01/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in.html

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example

```
:bufdo %s/oldStuff/newStuff/ge | update
```

just change your regex to fit your needs

Answer (score 5):

I think the best tool for this case is sed, the stream editor.

```
sed -i.old 's/:\([-a-z]*\)/\1:/' *.css
```

This will edit all your *.css* files leaving the original ones with the *.old* extensions.

The set of regular expressions used by sed is a bit different, and depending on your version more or less limited. The expression I used apparently works fine for your case — with the BSD tool.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of steps.

```
:vimgrep /^[^:]\w+/ %:p:h/*    " find all of the lines that don't start with a colon
```

This will put all of the matches into your quickfix list.

Then a macro to do what you want done.

```
qa
I:<esc>
f:x
:w|cn<enter>
q
```

Then test that macro a few times (with `@a`).
Then another macro to run that macro over and over again...

```
qbq   " this clears out b before starting, very important!
qb@a@bq
@b    " watch in amazement.  :)
```