# Using sed to match comma newline endbracket

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to write a sed statement that removes the last comma.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;$
CREATE TABLE person ($
  id int(11) NOT NULL,$
  name varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,$
  gender char(1) DEFAULT NULL,$
  birthdate date DEFAULT NULL,$
  deathdate date DEFAULT NULL,$
  height int(11) DEFAULT NULL,$
) ;$
```

code snippet is from vim with :set list

The wanted output is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;$
CREATE TABLE person ($
  id int(11) NOT NULL,$
  name varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,$
  gender char(1) DEFAULT NULL,$
  birthdate date DEFAULT NULL,$
  deathdate date DEFAULT NULL,$
  height int(11) DEFAULT NULL$
) ;$
```

I tryed to do it like this

```
sed -e 's@,$)@$)@'
```

but it does not match

Comment: last comma? Can you show expected output.

Comment: which comma are you atalking about ?

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` process one line of input at a time.  You need to append the next line to the current one, perform the substitution and print the pattern space:

```
sed 'N;s/,\n)/\n)/;P;D' inputfile
```

For your sample input, this would produce:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  gender char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  birthdate date DEFAULT NULL,
  deathdate date DEFAULT NULL,
  height int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

Comment: @aelor Could you please elaborate _doesnt work_?  Does it produce an error, or unexpected results?

Comment: Why split it up into 2 statements?

Comment: @potong Remove the split.  Thanks.

Comment: i dont knw why its behaving differently for me i am using ubuntu 12.04 and the above command doesnt remove any commas\

Comment: @aelor I suspect that you're considering the `$` at the end of lines to be a part of the input -- those are not a part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can act on files in vim with `argdo`.

This expression matched last comma: (using `/`)

`/,[\s\n]*)\s*;`

Also: [VIM, Run a command on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126789/vim-run-a-command-on-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you:

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/,\n\)/,"\n)")}7' file
```